# Is it possible to use images in swift documentation in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, image, documentation

I know it is possible in javadoc, but is this possible in swift documentation for Xcode? Either local images or from a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't include images for standard `Swift` documentation except Playgrounds. For playgrounds, you can check these links [Add resources to a playground](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev5516dfe72), [Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH17-SW1).